# SCCM 2016 и PXE Linux (нажатие F12)

Tags: windows, сервер

Всем привет.

Появилась необходимость поднять PXE Linux на серве с SCCM,но возникла проблема в том,что когда прописываю smsboot\x86\pxelinux.com в DHCP,то он грузится в PXE Linux без запроса F12. Как сделать так,чтобы он запрашивал нажатие какой-либо кнопки перед загрузкой,чтобы юзеры,у которых выставлена загрузка по сети не попадали случайно в PXE Linux

Comment: Я чёт нихрена не понял. На серваке только `pxelinux.com` и всё? большие никаких файлов? И что это за файл? откуда ты его взял и что именно он должен прогружать?

Comment: Я же написал,что поднял pxe linux,который входит в состав syslinux. На серве стандартный набор для pxe boot+pxe linux для загрузки iso.

Comment: Где писал? Где ссылки? Тут я ничего не вижу.

Comment: А какие ссылки нужны? Я написал что PXE Linux уже поднят,но в него может загрузиться любой юзер,у которого стоит загрузка по сети. F12 он требует только чтобы войти в Task Sequence

>Появилась необходимость поднять PXE Linux на серве с SCCM,но возникла проблема в том,что когда прописываю smsboot\x86\pxelinux.com в DHCP,то он грузится в PXE Linux без запроса F12.

Comment: Я вообще не помню, чтобы там можно было прожать каку-то кнопку с функцией "пресс эни кей ту континью". Можно просто сделать меню по умолчанию, которое по прошествии n милисекунд будет передавать загрузку винту.

Comment: Да,подбное сделал. Захайдил меню,и через три секунды без нажатия грузится хард. Ну раз нельзя,то ладно. Спасибо